# ADB connect to <IP> not working anymore or endless install process

Tags: android-studio, adb, adbwireless

I have a MacBook Pro 16 and Galaxy S10 combo and I used "wifi adb" over month by "WIFI ADB ULTIMATE" plugin, but once it broken and I can't connect to my device. I restarted the MB and the S10 many many times, I tried suggested solutions from other post but no final solution.
When I used "adb usb..." solution then I could connect but when I removed usb cable then I got an endless install process. I use same wifi on both devices.

```
$ adb kill-server && adb start-server && adb tcpip 5555 && adb connect 192.168.68.103
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
connected to 192.168.68.103:5555
```

For example I could connect but when I unplugged the usb cable I got this:

[image]

The android studio see the device (toolbar) but waiting for it.

So it's working only with USB cable.